# Unable to validate the JS variable in PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

i have three files index.html , getData.php and data.json

index.html ->

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
                            url: "getData.php",
                            type: "GET",
                            data: {variable: "loadavg"},
                            dataType:"json",
                            async: false
                            }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 800, height: 400});
    }
</script>
<ul class="list">
<p>Load average <input id="loadAvg" type="button" value="Enter" onclick="load();" /> </p>
 </ul>
```

getData.php ->

```
<?php 
// It reads a json formatted text file and outputs it.
if(isset($_GET["variable"]) == "loadavg"){
    $string = file_get_contents("data.json");
    echo $string;
     // if this works you should see in console 'graph on cosole'
    }
?>
```

data.json ->

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"HostName","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"CPU","type":"number"},
       {"id":"","label":"Free Avg memory","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"lp10b2vapp01,w10"},{"v":21}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"lp10b2vapp01,w10"},{"v":15}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"lp10b2vapp01,w10"},{"v":73}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"lp10b2vapp01,w10"},{"v":60}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"lp10b2vapp01,w10"},{"v":48}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"lp10b2vapp01,w10"},{"v":40}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"lp10b2vapp01,w10"},{"v":36}]}
      ]
}
```

when i click on button i was unable to see the output (Graph) ,Kindly look help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, this `if(isset($_GET["variable"]) == "loadavg"){` should be this `if(isset($_GET["variable"]) && $_GET["variable"] == "loadavg"){`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `async: false`. It's terribly bad practice as it locks the UI thread making the browser look to the user like it has crashed until the request completes. Instead use the async callbacks which `$.ajax` provides you to update the UI of the page once the request has finished. Try this:

```
function load() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "getData.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            variable: "loadavg"
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(jsonData) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart($('#chart_div')[0]);
            chart.draw(data, {
                width: 800, 
                height: 400
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Also note that you need to get the value of the parameter in the PHP code as well as checking it exists:

```
if (isset($_GET["variable"]) && $_GET["variable"] == "loadavg") 
{
    // code here...
}
```

Comment: @Rory, What if `async` is `false` and I am showing `css3` loader while `http` responds, will `loader` remain still(without animations) ? Excuse me for asking out of context question..

Comment: @RayonDabre the loader will remain still - assuming it even appears at all.

Comment: Tried similar thing(_show loader => make http post => hide loader_) in `sap-ui5` but loader did not come at all. I'm sure this got to do something with the `async : false`. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Rory McCrossan 
if (isset($_GET["variable"]) && $_GET["variable"] == "loadavg") 
{
    $string = file_get_contents("data.json");
    echo $string;
}
Please find the O/p here http://code.runnable.com/VqDAQxP4CNld5Xtw/output

Comment: i just now debugged in IE11 it's showing "load()" is un defined 
<p>Load average <input id="loadAvg" type="button" value="Enter" onclick="load();" /> </p> *load() is undefined"
   <p> </p>